# Dual voice output for PS4

Tags: ps4

I don't have a PS4 (but I am planning on getting one sometime soon). I've been looking for the answer to this for a while but I haven't been able to find a definite answer.

On the Xbox 360 (and probably Xbox One too, unsure about this), there is an option where you can output the audio from voice chat from other players to your headset, TV, or both simultaneously. Is there an option like this on the PS4? I know that the PS3 doesn't have this option at all, but I'm wondering if Sony implemented this feature for this gen.

Comment: It's unclear to me based on the answer what you are asking.  Are you asking if voice chat can be played through the TV and headset simultaneously? (the current answer does not answer this) I believe it might depend on the game, as I am pretty sure in the Destiny beta you could output chat through either or both.

Comment: @turbo Sorry, yes, that was exactly what I was asking. I saw the same thing when I was playing Destiny on my PS3, but it still made me curious whether Sony made it so you could do both, like the 360 can through a console setting.

Comment: I'm a bit busy, but I will check tonight to see if there is a system option

Answer (score 2):

Yes. The DualShock 4 controllers for PS4 have a jack socket to connect your headset to.
When connected, you can choose which sounds are sent to the headset. The options are:

- just voice chat,
- all sound (game + voice chat).

Whichever sound gets sent to your headset is no longer being sent to your TV.

Comment: This doesn't answer whether you can output voice chat only to the gamepad jack and not to the TV or not.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear about it. That's what I meant though. Will edit it in in a second.

Comment: -All- sound, including game? So basically if that option gets chosen, nothing comes out of the tv then?

Comment: @LOL.NO. Yes, that's correct.